# WalletConnect (Metamask Mobile) configuration with React Native app

Tags: metamask, react, web3-providers, walletconnect

Hey can anyone help me on below points-

1. Connect React Native (expo or xcode) Mobile App to Metamask Mobile Application with the help of Walletconnect

Not presenting the QRCode Modal but list of wallets available

2. Send Ethereum transaction to Metamask Mobile App

Please suggest an approach

Comment: Are you using the official WalletConnect library? It should have te option to configure which option you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

- wallet connect's dapp library https://www.npmjs.com/package/@walletconnect/react-native-dapp can be used to connect dApp with metamask wallet (List of wallets available on current device & which are supported by wallet connect will be displayed)
- To send Ethereum transaction use etherjs or wallet connect's web3provider using connector created above
  https://docs.walletconnect.com/quick-start/dapps/web3-provider